# JSON exception in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to execute query on database in the localhost and send the JSON object to the client in android. I m not been able to know what is the problem in my code. So some one please help me on this regard.

My php code is the one where i m sending the JSON object.
*php code*

query executed successfully..

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);


    $email=$row['EM'];
    $pass=$row['PASS'];

    $post=array("email"=>$email, "pass"=>$pass); 
    $posts[] = array("post"=>$post);
    //echo "SUCCESS";
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode(array("posts"=>$posts));
```

And in android side i ve this code below;

```
HttpResponse response = doPost(url, kvPairs);
        String responseBody=response.toString();
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS")==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Above part executes ..
Below code throws a JSON exception

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
    no_of_obj=jArray.length();
    nemail=new String[no_of_obj];
    npass=new String[no_of_obj];
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String s = e.getString("post");
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);
       Toast.makeText(context,jObject.getString("email")+":"+jObject.getString("pass") , duration).show();
        nemail[i]=jObject.getString("email");
        npass[i]=jObject.getString("pass");

    }
```

In the log cat i can see : The json string must begin with "{"....

Comment: Can you output the JSON object in the log and then post that here too? Sometimes if you have extra information at the beginning (say, a PHP warning or something) you won't know that until you look at the actual data returned from your API.

Comment: line # from the exception correlating with that last block of Java would be helpful

Comment: That means there is some problem with your url. Check the url in browser and see what you get. Otherwise there is some problem in your `doPost(url,kvpair)` method

Comment: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44ee70b8       This is what gets displayed in the logcat. And also the exception is in this line JSONObject= new JSONObject(responseBody);

Comment: in doPost no errors . I get the value in the php code i ve sent. and query also gets executed on database. Is there any error in encoding JSON object ?

Comment: [Follow it...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937517/keep-updating-new-json-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Probably you cannot do this

```
String s = e.getString("post");
```

because there is no "post" key in the array of Strings you have given,...

Try doing this,

```
String s = e.has("post")?e.getString("post"):null;
```

and then on next line keep a null check before Creating JSONObject..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$posts['data'] = $post;
//echo "SUCCESS";
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($posts);
```