# JSON in android throwing an exception

Tags: php, android, json

Suppose if i want to send a array from php (server side) and use it in Android how will i do it?

```
 $post=array("email"=>"email", "pass"=>"password");
 echo json_encode($post);
```

in Android :(response is HTTPResponse converted to string)

```
JSONObject j=new JSONObject(response);
```

The above line throws me an exception, Can some one help me in knowing what i m doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exception ?!

Comment: maybe you need to convert the response string as a valid json first?

Comment: You need to debug resulting response. Add something like `System.writeln(response)`

Comment: is it not the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937004/json-exception-in-android

Comment: **show the exact `logcat` output.**

Comment: can you show the response string

Comment: Try it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937517/keep-updating-new-json-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Get String from HttpResponse by following:
Lets assume httpResponse is the httpResponse returned by execute method, now do the follwoing to get String from it:

```
HttpEntity entity=httpResponse.getEntity();
String response= EntityUtils.toString(entity)
```

Now create JSONObject from it:

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: Hardly. Associative arrays in php are encoded as objects in json.

Comment: I can't, casue I'm not the one, who asked.

Comment: This is my response string org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44ee70b8

Comment: This is not a string, and if this is response String, you are not doing proper steps to get response from server